# unresolved external symbol error even though the function exists char*

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, linker-errors

I have two projects in one solution in Visual Studio. One of the projects (application) depends on another (library). The library has a method:

```
int foo(_TCHAR*);
```

It is properly defined in header and implemented. In the application I call the method like this:

```
int bar(_TCHAR* str) {
  return foo(str);
}
```

The error I am getting is

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl
>   foo(char *)"

The method signature is exactly the same and the same type of variable is being used.

Comment: Before casting your votes please note that this is a self-answered question. It took me quite a lot of time to find the problem and I hope that this Q&A will help others too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason behind the linker not being able to match the methods is the mismatched `Character Set` option in projects `General Properties` page.

The library project had this option set to `Use Unicode Character Set` and the application to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.

Unifying the Character Set in both projects fixed this error.

Comment: Wow. Visual Studio strikes again.